# How can I save array of Dictionary in CoreData?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, core-data

How can I store the data in CoreData ? I'm using this to display it in my tableView cells but how can I save and retrieve from my database ?

Here is the code:

```
var arrOfDict = [[String :AnyObject]]()
var dictToSaveNotest = [String :AnyObject]()

class SecondViewController: UIViewController {

   @IBAction func addItem(_ sender: Any)
{
        dictToSaveNotest.updateValue(notesField.text! as AnyObject, forKey: "notesField")
        arrOfDict.append(dictToSaveNotest)
}
```

and then to view in tableViewCell, I used the code:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CustomCellID") as! CustomCell
cell.textView.text = arrOfDict[indexPath.row]["notesField"] as! String!

}
```

I tried this in my `addItem`

```
 let context = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext
        let task = Task(context: context)
        task.notes=notesField.text!

        //save the data to coreData
        (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).saveContext()
```

but not sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, that would generally be how you'd save to Core Data. You create an instance of the object. Set the properties and then save. Are you receiving any errors? Or do you just want to be sure that your code works?

If you want to verify that your code works, the best thing to do would be to try to access the saved data. If you can see your saved data retrieved from your database, then your code worked :)

In order to save your input as a `Task` object, if you have a `textField` and a `notesField` on your screen to take input, you'd do something like this:

```
let task = Task(context: context)
task.title = textField.text
task.notes = notesField.text
//save the data to coreData
(UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).saveContext()
```

Comment: what my code is doing is, it is saving data like a big string instead of saving it in different dictionaries. I want my `textField`(which is in my `tableView`) to have the data stored in array of Dictionary of `notesField`

Comment: iOS will not be smart and separate out your dictionary for you :) If you assign the dictionary (as text) to a String property, it will save the text in one field :) You would need to go through the dictionary and extract each value and set it for the correct property on your Task object. I'll add some pseudo-code to my answer to explain better.

Comment: Cant figure it out, can you help :) ?https://gist.github.com/raunakstrikha/cf87d92796412d9f1a5a79d6c0382542

Comment: Taking a look now. Will update my answer once I have an answer for you.

Comment: @S.Verma In `SecondViewController` what are the values from on screen fields that you want to save? And what is the structure of `Task` so that I know which properties you are dealing with? Also, are you able to share the full project code with me? That would make answering things much faster :)

Comment: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BzWwjHdOZO2LM1NXTzhhQzdLSGs here is the full project. There are some errors, because I'm working on it you can comment them if it gives any error :)

Comment: Will do :) Will get back to you in a little bit once I've had time to check.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138880/discussion-between-s-verma-and-fahim).

Comment: I have some issues regarding the datePicker.

Comment: What are the issues you're running into?

Comment: I sent a message in the chat